# Remove parts of a string after a specific character

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem:
I was using file_get_contents() on a google search in my PHP program, but whenever i click on the links it takes me to a page called /url? and a random string of letters and numbers are in the url on my server. What i want to do is remove everything in the url that is in this tag using possibly php without removing everything after the &amp part of the url in this snippet of code:

```html
<a href="/url?q=https://www.dictionary.com/browse/something&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjrxPm33a7nAhWSZ80KHfVUC_sQFjAKegQICRAB&amp;usg=AOvVaw3d2t7GukCiuBVOJOqc29Us"><div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">Something | Definition of Something at Dictionary.com</div><div class="BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd">https://www.dictionary.com › browse › something</div></a>
```

My full source code at the moment is below:

```php
<style>
  .KP7LCb { display:none;}
  #extrares { display:none;}
  .bz1lBb { display:none;}
  .cOl4Id { display:none;}
</style>

<?php
  $google = file_get_contents("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google");
  $google1 = str_replace("/url?q=", "", $google);

  echo $google1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to do three things in sequence:

1. Parse HTML.
2. Parse a URL.
3. Parse a query string.

A possible tool for the first task (though it might be considered overkill here) is a DOM parser, e.g.:

```
// Error checking omitted
$html = '<a href="/url?q=https://www.dictionary.com/browse/something&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjrxPm33a7nAhWSZ80KHfVUC_sQFjAKegQICRAB&amp;usg=AOvVaw3d2t7GukCiuBVOJOqc29Us"><div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">Something | Definition of Something at Dictionary.com</div><div class="BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd">https://www.dictionary.com › browse › something</div></a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$url = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')[0]->getAttribute('href');
```

Once you have the URL, you can get the query fragment:

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

... and finally parse it:

```
parse_str($query, $get);
$link = $get['q'];
```

Comment: Why don't you look at my code on repl.it? The url is: https://repl.it/@venhubtech/MetaSearch-Yahoo-Google-Bing and look at google.php